# Object dependency in Java (with listeners, in libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've got a main class containing

```
registerscreen = new registerScreen(this);
emailRegisterscreen = new emailRegisterScreen(this);
```

The `registerScreen` contains a emailButton, with a listener, made in the constructor:

```
emailButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            Gdx.app.log("registerscreen", "email clicked");
            gameHolder.setScreen(gameHolder.emailRegisterscreen);
        }
    });
```

`gameHolder` is the main class.

Now, this above example only works if I initialize `emailRegisterscreen` before `emailScreen` (the snippet above does not work). I was wondering if it's possible to get it working and still defining the registerscreen first?

I'm guessing Java uses the current value of `gameHolder.emailRegisterscreen` instead of a reference to it or something.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, is it returning a null pointer exception? Is it doing nothing? The anonymous class will use the current value of gameHolder when the touchUp method is called.

Comment: *"I'm guessing Java uses the current value of `gameHolder.emailRegisterscreen` instead of a reference to it or something."* No this is not the case, Java uses the value of the field at the moment of execution. So the order of registering is (in your example code snippet) not important. I guess there is something else wrong with your code. You might want to elaborate what is not working, do you get an error, is there nothing happening?

Answer (score 0):

Aaaand I've figured it out.

I had a line

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

In both the constructors of my screens. This caused the second screen to override the input processor, whilst the user was being shown the first screen. (Hence I got not errors!)

Fix:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

Added this to both my Screens.